# Given $x''+q(t)x=0$ and $q(t)\leq 0$ for all $t$, the solution $x$ is such that $x(t_0)>0,x'(t_0)>0$. Prove that $x(t)>0$ for all $t>t_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $x''+q(t)x=0$ and $q(t)\leq 0$ for all $t$, the solution $x$ is such that $x(t_0)>0,x'(t_0)>0$.
Prove that $x(t)>0$ for all $t>t_0$

I know that if I show that $x''(t)\geq0$ for all $t>t_0$ it will show the needed result but i only got that $x''(t_0)\geq 0$

Comment: $x^{''} = p(t)x$, where $p(t) \ge 0$.  $x(t_0 +  dt) \approx x(t_0) +  dtx'(t_0) > x(t_0)$.  And $x^{''}(t_0) \ge 0 \implies x^{'}(t_0 +  dt) > x^{'}(t_0)$.  Since the second derivative will always be the same sign as $x$, unless one of them is zero, we can extend that argument...?

Comment: @GingerBreadMan for all d>0 we get the desired result no?

Comment: Yes, the result will hold for all $t > t_0$.  You can always try using integrals to extend the infinitesimal observations.  $x,x',x^{''}$ are all nonnegative at $t_0$.  Since the change in $x$ is driven by $x'$, $x$ will not decrease from $t_0$ until $x'$ goes negative.  But $x'$ can't go negative until $x^{''}$ has gone negative.  But $x^{''}$ is bound to either be zero, or have the same sign as $x$, so it can't go negative.  Hence $x'(t) \ge x'(t_0)$ for all $t > t_0$.

Comment: If you write it as answer I'll accept it